# Two TextViews shows exclusively on a line using XML

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

My ListView item has two TextViews. I want to show one of them at a time **using XML**. I don't want to do this programmatically. How to do it?

For example: 
When TextView A has text, TextView B disappears. When TextView A is empty, TextView B appears.

[image]

My code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/groupNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textColor="@color/ForestGreen"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topRatedPlaceNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20dip" 
        android:textColor="@color/Azure"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, you cant do that with xml, by Programmatically in your `getView()` of List's Adapter check like

```
if(textview1.getText().toString.length()>0)
     textview2.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
else
     textview1.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

TextView A has a text then in TextView B set setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) or setVisibility(View.VGONE) and same for TextView B. you do this in your CustomAdapter Class getView Method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Will you ever have both of them shown with text at the same time ? If not, and if you don't have style difference (text size/color), you could just use a single text view ?

Else, if A and B have different size / color / font / whatever, and assuming they will never be having text at the same time, using wrap_content as you do should ensure that A gets a width of 0 when it has no text, and B will take all the space. Else, if B has no text, A will take as much space as needed by its content.